# How to encrypt form data before submitting?

Tags: php, forms, encryption, openssl, submit

I need to encrypt some input fields before sending data to my php script which starts a cURL login to another website!

I started to generate a pair of keys and my encryption/decryption just works fine.

```
<?php

// data to encrypt
$data = "TestPassword";

// ==== ENCRYPT ====

$pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_public('file://public.pem');
openssl_public_encrypt($data, $en, $pubKey);

echo $en;

// ==== DECRYPT ====

$passphrase = '123456789987654321';

$privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private('file://private.pem', $passphrase);
openssl_private_decrypt($en, $sen, $privateKey);

echo $sen;
?>
```

I did not find anything helpful concerning my problem ! How to build this small form - which encrypts first and decrypts later @ decrypt.php ?

```
<form action="decrypt.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="ID" />
<input type="password" name="password" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Do I have to use JS for the client ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can't encrypt it directly before submitting the data - any encryption would need to include the private keys in a public place thus defeating the point. As long as your website is using https using a valid and up to date certificate that should be all the encryption you need.

Comment: At the moment I don't want to spent money for an up to date certificate! Is there any other free of charge possibility to send my form data in a safe manner to my script ?

Comment: You can self sign an SSL certificate, which gives you the encryption but no "trust" - a user must explicitly say they trust your site in order to use it. It's fine for testing but *never* use a self signed certificate for production/public use. You can also get free SSL protection using CloudFlare: https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl

Comment: You can get a 'real' SSL certificate signed by a trusted CA (Geotrust) for ~$10.00/yr through NameCheap:  https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/geotrust/rapidssl.aspx